# What is the difference - const int x = 5000; and const int x = 50'00; in C++?

Tags: c++, constants, variable-assignment

What is the difference in following c++ codes -

```
const int x = 5000;
const int x = 50'00;
```

Comment: Second requires C++14 or higher.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since C++14 you are allowed to put a *digit separator* `'` *anywhere* within an integer literal (apart from the beginning or the end or just after the base indicator not including the octal leading zero - otherwise you'd clash with *muticharacter literals*.)

The intention is to make code more readable: e.g.

```
const int x = 5'000;
```

or, using Indian notation (which explains the *anywhere* rationale)

```
const auto x = 12'34'567;
```

or, in hexadecimal

```
const auto x = 0xee'ef;
```

Note that the *type* of something like `1e3` is a `double`, which can bite you hard, especially when used in a `for` loop as a counter.

Reference: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal

Comment: The rationale is just about the same as allowing non-English function/variable names (apart from the latter being much harder to detect...). I do not consider recommendable using any of both (digit notation/names) in non-English variants...

Answer (score 10):

`50'00` uses [digit separator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) that was added in C++14. The number will resolve to `5000`, only difference is that it might be easier to read. Usually you would use digit separator to separate thousands, like `1'000'000`, but you are allowed to use it at any point in the number.

Comment: (Note that different cultures separate digits differently. Notably, in India, `1'000'000'000'000` would be written as `1'00'000'00'00'000`. Thus, the language doesn't enforce the grouping.)

Comment: @Amadan Being allowed - sure, recommendable? Arguable at least... It reduces code readability tremendously for anybody not adhering this very specific culture, just analogously to using non-English function/variable names...